# how can we fix rotation of screen in codenameone?

Tags: lwuit, codenameone

I am making a application in code name one, and as my requirement I want my screen fix.

like only portrait view or landscape view. How we can do it?

Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `Display.getInstance().canForceOrientation()` and `Display.getInstance().lockOrientation(boolean)`. Notice that not all devices support orientation locking.